# How to restrict list in search results but not list item in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am having multiple lists and list items. I have configured share point search in my Intranet Site. This is all working fine but I don't want to show list Url with allitem.aspx like [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXUD1.png).

I want only list item to come in my search not list name with allitems.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Search the web for info on how to create a custom search results page.
There you can do and show whatever you want.
Start here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ol8ZpzV1qVI